# date_sub function unrecognized in EasyPHP

Tags: php, date, xampp, easyphp

Hello i have writte a php script that uses date_sub function of php to substract a number from a date (eg.-1 date from date).
I had up and running using xampp(my server) perfectly but in easyphp it shows an error as "unrecognised command" for date_sub.

Anyone knows anything about this error?
I used xaamp 3.2.1 with PHP 5.4.22

I am not sure what version of php was on easyPHP(not my server) but i think it was the lastest available.
(i can check it)

Comment: Yes, check your PHP version. It's likely too old (< 5.3).

Answer (score 0):

date_sub should be avaiable from PHP 5.3.0 so it would apear your not using 5.4.22 as you think.

If you cant update you can get roughly the same functionality by using [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$date = time();
$date = strtotime("-8 days",$date);
$date = strtotime("-8 hours",$date);
```

etc.